# Как загрузить на Google Map маркеры из Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Всем привет! Делаю приложение на android, суть которого в создании карты, куда бы пользователи могли добавлять свои метки (маркеры), которые сохраняются в Firebase. С сохранением проблем нет, маркеры заносятся, сохраняются их координаты и title. А вот при прочтении данных из базы либо возникают ошибки, либо просто ничего не работает.

База данных выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методы по добавлению маркеров в базу и чтению из нее:

public class MarkersDataBase {

```
static DatabaseReference mDatabase;
static double latitude;
static double longitude;
static String title;

public static void addMarkersOnDatabase(){
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Markers");

    latitude = MapsActivity.currentLatLng.latitude;
    longitude = MapsActivity.currentLatLng.longitude;

    String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
    String lon = String.valueOf(longitude);
    title = MapsActivity.defaultTitle;

    HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    dataMap.put("latitude", lat);
    dataMap.put("longitude", lon);
    dataMap.put("title", title);

    mDatabase.push().setValue(dataMap);
}

public static void addMarkersFromDatabaseOnMap(){
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Markers");
    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
            String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

            LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            MapsActivity.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(location)
                    .title(dataSnapshot.getKey()));
        }


    });

}
```

}

На строке String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString(); выдается ошибка:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Как можно ее исправить?
Может быть метод по загрузке маркеров из базы вообще в корне не верный, как сделать лучше?

Comment: Выведите в логи что вам приходит в onChildAdded для начала. И не хардкодьте ключи - одна опечатка и всё летит к чертям. Вынесите строки в константы

Comment: предполагаю, что координаты нужно приводить к `double`

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает этот код

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("places");

    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            if(dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue() != null &&
                    dataSnapshot.child("lng").getValue() != null) {

                double lat = (double) dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
                double lng = (double) dataSnapshot.child("lng").getValue();
                LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(location)
                        .title(dataSnapshot.getKey()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```